# Azure: Function stops working when trying to get blob content

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am working with nodeJS and Azure functions. I am trying to get the content of a blob (pptx) and then further work with that pptx (unzip it with admzip).

However, whenever I try to get the content, the function just stops without any error and after some time it times out. I tried getting the properties of the blob first (to check if the blob exists) and that works.

Here is my function:

```
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'storage-account';
const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = 'storage-key';
let AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
let fs = require('file-system');

const blobService = storage.createBlobService(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    getBlobProperties('default-powerpoint', 'download.pptx').then((properties) => {
        context.log('Properties: ', properties);
        getBlobContent('default-powerpoint', 'download.pptx').then((content) => {
            context.log('Blob Content: ', content);
        })
    });
};

function getBlobProperties(containerName, fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.getBlobProperties(
            containerName,
            fileName,
            function (err, properties, status) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(properties);
                }
            });
    })
}

function getBlobContentAsStream(containerName, fileName, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, fileName, res, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
            }
        });
    })
}

function getBlobContent(containerName, blobName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.getBlobToText(
            containerName,
            blobName,
            function (err, blobContent, blob) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        'content': blobContent,
                        'blob': blob
                    });
                }
            });
    })
}
```

As you can see I tried both `getBlobToStream` and `getBlobToText` but with the same result. The `getBlobProperties` works fine and I get all the information about the blob, just not the content.

Can anyone please help me get the content of the blob.

*Edit*:

This is the output of the properties if anyone is interested:

```
BlobResult {
  container: 'default-powerpoint',
  name: 'download.pptx',
  metadata: {},
  lastModified: 'Wed, 14 Aug 2019 08:28:16 GMT',
  creationTime: 'Wed, 14 Aug 2019 08:28:16 GMT',
  etag: '"something"',
  blobType: 'BlockBlob',
  contentLength: '4658',
  serverEncrypted: 'true',
  requestId: 'someID',
  contentSettings: { contentType: 'image/jpeg' },
  lease: { status: 'unlocked', state: 'available' },
  copy: 
   { id: 'id123',
     status: 'success',
     source: 'sourceURL',
     progress: '4658/4658',
     bytesCopied: 4658,
     totalBytes: 4658,
     completionTime: 'Wed, 14 Aug 2019 08:28:16 GMT' } }
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but why is your content type of 'image/jpeg' ?

Comment: Also is this runtime v1 or v2? and which version of node?

Comment: @AdamMarczak its node version 11.9 and Runtime version: 2.0.12641.0 (~2). The content type can be ignored (i added an image to see if its a problem with the powerpoint type and forgot to add the output of the pptx but despite the content type the output is exactly the same, will update later)

Comment: Remember also in 2.0 you either need to call `context.done();` or export async function `module.exports = async function`. But I'm not certain that this is an issue, I will check on this when I get back home.

Comment: @AdamMarczak thank you! I will try out the context.done() and will update the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get solve this to work using code

```
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const fs = require('fs');

const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '<account_name>';
const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = '<access_key>';

const blobService = storage.createBlobService(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

function getBlobContentAsStream(containerName, fileName, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, fileName, fs.createWriteStream('task1-download.txt'), function(error, serverBlob) {
            if(!error) {
                resolve(serverBlob);
            } else { 
                reject(err); 
            }
        });
    })
}

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    context.log('Starting...');

    getBlobContentAsStream('default-powerpoint', 'download.pptx').then((content) => {
        context.log('Blob Content: ', content);
        context.done();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log.error(err);
        context.done();
    });

};
```

And trace output

[image]

The problem that happens in your code you can actually see in Application Insights trace if you connected Functions to it. You didn't get any errors because you didn't add error handling for your `then` callback executor.

```
getBlobContent('default-powerpoint', 'download.pptx').then((content) => {
    context.log('Blob Content: ', content);
    context.done();
})
```

Use

```
getBlobContent('default-powerpoint', 'download.pptx').then((content) => {
    context.log('Blob Content: ', content);
    context.done();
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    context.done();
}))
```

You would see

[image]

With details

[image]

```
Error: An incorrect number of bytes was read from the connection. 
The connection may have been closed.
```

So the problem you are having with `getBlobToText` is that it tries to return Buffer object as string and it fails to validate MD5. I read somewhere it's possible to using write to stream function to write to buffer instead of file but I can't find it right now.

I would probably grab some NodeJS memory stream library and try output it there as I would assume you don't want to save directly to file. But maybe you do, decide yourself.

[image]

If you would end up using 'fs' library remember to use recommended safe non blocking patterns like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

module.exports = async function (context) {
    try {
        const data = await readFileAsync('./hello.txt');
    } catch (err) {
        context.log.error('ERROR', err);
        // This rethrown exception will be handled by the Functions Runtime and will only fail the individual invocation
        throw err;
    }
    context.log(`Data from file: ${data}`);
}
```

Comment: @threxx did this help? Have you tested this?

Comment: yes the error handling works. What do you mean by "I would assume you don't want to save directly to file"? I need the file, change something and then save it back, would that still work with the fs library  and streams?

Comment: I meant saving directly to file system as 'file.pptx' is not recommended as you might get into issues when executing this in parallel. Best solution is using in memory streams rather than saving it on system drive.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code i have used in my app

```
  return new Promise(async r => {
            bst.getBlobToText(containername, name, (err, text) => r(err ? null : text));
  })
```

[Full SourceCode](https://github.com/sajeetharan/azure-storage_node/tree/master/src)

Comment: I recreated OP scenario and tested it using your code. Error message is the same `An incorrect number of bytes was read from the connection. The connection may have been closed` so this doesn't solve it unfortunately. Your code will work for text files not binary buffer files.

Answer (score 1):

Might be the issue is that the api is changed. I just checked below, callback function takes only two arguments in `getBlobToText`:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-node-quickstart/blob/master/index.js

```
const downloadBlob = async (containerName, blobName) => {
    const dowloadFilePath = path.resolve('./' + blobName.replace('.txt', '.downloaded.txt'));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.getBlobToText(containerName, blobName, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({ message: `Blob downloaded "${data}"`, text: data });
            }
        });
    });
};
```